# Xcode 9 Server duplicate provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, provisioning-profile, xcode-server

I have set up an Xcode 9 Server with manual signing. Everytime i update my provisioning profiles (PP) in the developer portal it adds a new PP to the server. Even when i remove the PP it remains in the list.

[image]

Any ideas how to clean this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode/Xcode Server will keep provisioning profiles until they expire. So even removed ones from the developer portal will remain. You can forcefully delete profiles from there stored paths on the system.

You can access all of the Provisioning Profiles downloaded for Xcode at the path:

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
```

And all of the Provisioning Profiles for Xcode Server at:

```
/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles/
```